# SFML not loading font file properly?

Tags: c++, fonts, sfml

I'm trying to load a font file and system says it exists but there's some sort of error with SFML??

here's the snippet of code

```cpp
// Get current working directory
std::filesystem::path currentPath = std::filesystem::current_path();

// Construct absolute path to the font file
std::string fontFilename = "ComicSansMS3.ttf"; // Adjust filename as needed
std::filesystem::path fontPath = currentPath / fontFilename;

// Check if the file exists
bool fileExists = std::filesystem::exists(fontPath);

// Output path location and file existence
std::cout << "Current working directory: " << currentPath << std::endl;
std::cout << "Font file path: " << fontPath << std::endl;
std::cout << "File exists: " << (fileExists ? "Yes" : "No") << std::endl;

//adding font
sf::Font font;
if (!font.loadFromFile("ComicSansMS3.ttf")) {
    std::cerr << "Error loading font" << std::endl;
    return 1;
}
```

and here's the result:

```
Current working directory: "C:\\Users\\name\\source\\repos\\project\\project"
Font file path: "C:\\Users\\name\\source\\repos\\project\\project\\ComicSansMS3.ttf"
File exists: Yes
Failed to load font "" (failed to create the font face)
Error loading font
```

Comment: Check the file path, try using absolute path (just for checking) and check file permissions (read permissions should be there I think).

Comment: You have the correct font path in `fontPath`. Why do you use the static string with just the filename `font.loadFromFile("ComicSansMS3.ttf")` for the load attempt instead of the existing and already verified path in `fontPath`?